# How to run the CPU at something like 75%?

Tags: windows-xp, cpu, speed, cpu-speed

My notebook is too old for me to invest into a new fan (it will simply be replaced by a new one when the final heat death occurs), but when it runs on full speed I feel like sitting in front of a vacuum cleaner with integrated cooking... I'm currently using [NHC](http://www.pbus-167.com/), the Max Battery mode of which let's the CPU run at 50% (~800 MHz). That's fine for most applications, and both temperature and noise remain low. However, on some occasions I need a bit more speed, more around 75% maybe.

Can I set the power saving settings somehow so that the CPU won't surpass 75% of it's capability so that an acceptable compromise between power and noise is achieved? I can't set the CPU frequency in the BIOS and since on rare occasions I'd like to be able to switch to 100% without much hassling, hardware solutions like setting jumpers are no option.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/145332/slowing-down-cpu-speed/145426#145426) to a similar (linux!) question mentions NHC should be able to offer these options, but for me they are all greyed out:

[image: screenshot of NHC with greyed-out options I ask for...]

The notebook is an Asus Z9200K, I guess NHC doesn't support its chipset enough for these advanced options.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/292936/how-to-slow-down-my-cpu but XP doesn't seem to offer these advanced energy saving settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I use RealTemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) to modulate the clock to reduce processor loads and temps. Not sure if this will work with your processor or not.

Open RealTemp and click the settings button

.
[image]

Then tick Clock Modulation and set the % of modulation you want, this is not % of processor power necissarily, so you may need a lower setting than you think, you may have to experiment some, I use 37.5% when encoding movies to reduce temps on a first gen core i5 processor in my Notebook.

.
[image]

Comment: aww... It looks like just what I wanted but it doesn't support the AMD Turion64 :-( still, +1

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler See if this one will work for the Turion...http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the risk you could open your laptop and clean out all the dust. It can make a big difference.

Comment: thanks, I already did that, it helped only litte - I guess the fan is past its best times...